# I want to create a persistent mapped network drive with ftp

Tags: powershell

I want to create a persistent mapped network drive with ftp. I have mounted already a ftp path with the file explorer of windows in order to not input the credentials again. What is the solution please?

Here is my code:

```
New-PSDrive -Persist -Name "X" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root "ftp://localhost/"
```

I have this error:

> New-PSDrive: D:\powershell\Untitled-2.ps1:1:1
> Line 1
> New-PSDrive -Persist -Name "X" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root "ftp:// …
>
> ```
> When you use the Persist parameter, the root must be a file system location on a remote computer.
> ```

Comment: id look into the following https://www.ferrobackup.com/map-ftp-as-disk.html

Comment: thank you very much! it works!

Comment: Good to know (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me clarify few of the things.
Mapped network drives are saved in Windows on the local computer. They're persistent, not session-specific,and can be viewed and managed in File Explorer and other tools.
When you scope the command locally, without dot-sourcing, the Persist parameter doesn't persist the creation of a PSDrive beyond the scope in which you run the command. If you run `New-PSDrive` inside a script, and you want the new drive to persist indefinitely, you must dot-source the script. For best results, to force a new drive to persist, specify Global as the value of the Scope parameter and include Persist in your command.
The name of the drive must be a letter, such as `D` or `E`. The value of Root parameter must be a UNC path of a different computer. The PSProvider parameter's value must be `FileSystem`.

So technically, you dont need to persist, you just need to specify the `-Root` properly:

```
New-PSDrive -PSProvider filesystem -Root C:\full\path\ -Name anyname
```

In your case the full path would be an UNC path `\\remoteserver\full\path` of FTP

Comment: Ok, so If I understand, it is not possible to create a mapped network drive with the FTP protocol.I want to use FTP for security reasons.

Comment: @geekdu972: Yup, you got it right, It's not possible to use FTP as protocol and map a drive with it. For security reasons, you need to use the FTP clients and better to use SFTP or FTPS rather. But it is never possible to have the Drive mapped and have it used FTP as protocol. If it answers your question, then acceptance of the answer would be appreciable