How to mount FTP folder as local disk
I'm trying to mount an FTP network folder as a local drive, similar to how the Google Drive application mounts its network drive
This is my first time working with FTP and network connections.
Reading other answers and forums I have the following NuGet packages installed:

Cake.Powershell
FluentFTP
Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure

This is my code:
private void bAnadir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string remotePath = @"ftpPath";

    string username = "user";
    string password = "paswrd";

    char driveLetter = 'S';

    driveLetter = FirstAvailableLetter(driveLetter);

    MountFTP(remotePath, username, password, driveLetter);

    MessageBox.Show($"FTP '{remotePath}' was mounted as drive {driveLetter}: successfully.");
}

private void MountFTP(string ftpPath, string username, string password, char driveLetter)
{
    string cmd = $"New-PSDrive -Name {driveLetter} -PSProvider FileSystem -Root {ftpPath} -Credential (New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('{username}', (ConvertTo-SecureString '{password}' -AsPlainText -Force)))";
    RunPowerShellCommand(cmd);
}

private void RunPowerShellCommand(string command)
{
    using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        PowerShellInstance.AddScript(command);

        WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo();
        PowerShellInstance.Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);

        PowerShellInstance.Runspace.Open();

        Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();

        foreach (PSObject outputItem in PSOutput)
        {
            if (outputItem != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(outputItem.BaseObject.GetType().FullName);
                Console.WriteLine(outputItem.BaseObject.ToString() + "\n");
            }
        }

        if (PowerShellInstance.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (ErrorRecord error in PowerShellInstance.Streams.Error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Error: {error.Exception.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}

static bool IsLetterAvailable(char driveLetter)
{
    DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
    foreach (DriveInfo drive in allDrives)
    {
        if (drive.IsReady && string.Equals(drive.Name.Substring(0, 1), driveLetter.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

static char FirstAvailableLetter(char preferredDriveLetter)
{
    char driveLetter = preferredDriveLetter;

    if (IsLetterAvailable(driveLetter))
    {
        return driveLetter;
    }

    for (char letter = 'D'; letter <= 'Z'; letter++)
    {
        if (IsLetterAvailable(letter))
        {
            return letter;
        }
    }

    return '0';
}

Thanks a lot!!

Your question is very broad and confusing. I'm afraid that what you want to achieve is very complicated task. I believe that you cannot use New-PSDrive to map FTP as a drive. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/66372071/850848.

@MartinPrikryl reading the question you sent me, it would not be possible to leave a persistent unit then, I had found apps that leave you a folder inside an already created unit, I will then change the approach to do that, thank you very much!

You might be after WebDAV rather than FTP perhaps to mount as a Windows Drive. Also see https://www.reddit.com/r/NoStupidQuestions/comments/uzjfdr/what_protocol_does_google_drive_use_for_data/, Google Drive isn't FTP afaik.

@BitcoinMurderousManiac Thank you for the contribution! I will review the publication and discuss with colleagues whether continuing to use FTP is the most comfortable and secure or better to use other protocols.
